# Flutter: How to properly perform CRUD actions either in static method or background service

Tags: flutter, sqlite

I use `android_alarm_manager_plus` to trigger a static function that also starts a background service. I would like to perform CRUD actions either in the static method or in the service, as I need to update the database when the alarm triggers.

Besides this issue, I would also like to edit the database from the main app thread

As far as I am concerned, trying to edit the database from a static method or background service could cause synchronization issues. What is the best approach for this situation?